# Assign class attribute from async function inside a constructor

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have the following code

```
class RequestHeaders {
 getdata = async () => {
    let settings = await OfficeClass.GetLocalData("user-credentials").then(settings => { return settings });
   if (settings) {
  this.url = settings.url;
  this.oauthtoken = settings.oauthtoken;
  this.oauthverifier = settings.oauthsecret;
  this.loginType = settings.loginType;
  this.basicLogin = settings.basicLogin;
  this.isServiceDeskCustomer = settings.isServiceDeskCustomer;
  this.isCookieLogin = settings.isServiceDeskCustomer;
  this.cookie = settings.basicLogin;
}

}
 constructor() {
this.url = "";
this.oauthtoken = "";
this.oauthverifier = "";
this.loginType = "";
this.basicLogin = "";
this.isServiceDeskCustomer = "";
this.isCookieLogin = "";
this.cookie = "";
this.getdata();

}

 headers = (query) => {
if (this.loginType == "basic") {
  return {
    isBasicLogin: "true",
    authentication: this.basicLogin,
    Pragma: "no-cache",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
  };
} else if (this.loginType == "customer") {
  return {
    iscookielogin: "true",
    cookiekey: this.basicLogin,
    Pragma: "no-cache",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
  };
}
else {
  return {
    isBasicLogin: "false",
    token_access: this.oauthtoken,
    token_secret: this.oauthverifier,
    Pragma: "no-cache",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
  };
}
};
}

static getProjects = (ServerVersion) => {
const reqHeader = new RequestHeaders();
debugger
this.url = reqHeader.url;
const header = reqHeader.headers();
let headers = {
  ...header,
  url: this.url + UtilsJiraApi.getProjects(ServerVersion),
};
return axios.get(Utils.serverURL() + "get", {
  headers: headers,
});
};
```

I am calling `const reqHeader = new RequestHeaders();` which basically should return `reqHeader` parameters filled with data coming from the async function, but it is not the case
`this.url` inside `getProjects` is always empty

I know using an async await inside a constructor is not the best practice but how can I refactor my code fulfill my needs?

Answer (score 1):

A constructor returns (obviously) synchronously. The code hat follows below an `await` can only execute when the current flow of execution comes to an end first. So you can only hope to use the *results* of that asynchronous code in a block that is also executed asynchronously.

So to make this possible, don't call `.getdata()` from within the constructor, but let `getProjects` make that call. This has as advantage that it can `await` that call, and execute the rest of the code asynchronously.

Another remark: `.then(settings => { return settings })` is not doing anything useful. You can omit it.

Here is how the `getProjects` code could look (don't forget to remove `this.getData()` from the constructor):

```
static getProjects = async (ServerVersion) => {
//                   ^^^^^
    const reqHeader = new RequestHeaders();
    await reqHeader.getdata();  // <-- add the call here & await the promise
    this.url = reqHeader.url;
    const header = reqHeader.headers();
    let headers = {
        ...header,
        url: this.url + UtilsJiraApi.getProjects(ServerVersion),
    };
    return axios.get(Utils.serverURL() + "get", {
        headers: headers,
    });
};
```